# What OpenCV cascade choose for facial recognition

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, svm, image-recognition

OpenCV includes a lot of of LBP and HAAR cascades, i know the basic difference between LBP and Haar methods. In general terms, Haar is more reliable and LBP is faster, but among the directories are different cascades, in both cases, for facial recognition. What is the difference among this Haar and LBP cascades, what would i choose for an access system based in facial recognition?

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data

Comment: Have you looked inside those XML files? They usually contain description of what they are trained to detect.

Comment: @m3h0w thanks, but the descriptions are too generic to be helpful to me

Comment: You didn't explain in your question what do you want to know about them, so a perfectly valid answer to the question "What is the difference among Haar and LBP cascades?" would be "some of them are for frontal faces and some are for cats"

Comment: try all or even use multiple at the same time! Differences  are: Some use Haar, some use LBP and different used different training datasets and/or different parameters.